# 415 on fetch POST with multipart FormData

Tags: fetch, multipartform-data, form-data, http-status-code-415

I have been going over countless posts and I am just stumped with this which should be so simple.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('message', payload.message);
formData.append('attachment', this.state.attachment);
let options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
}
fetch('api/contact', options);
```

Then I get the all too familiar 415 error:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44348/api/contact
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 415 
Remote Address: [::1]:44348
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I know not to set my Content-Type and even the headers and everything look fine including the boundary:

**Request Headers**

```
:authority: localhost:44348
:method: POST
:path: /api/contact
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 10269
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5iTqTV6AaKla3BMA
origin: https://localhost:44348
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://localhost:44348/contact
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
```

**Form Data**

```
message: asdasd
attachment: (binary)
```

This is the same API I previously used with and old jQuery site and it worked fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: is the `;` after `formData` in the options a typo in the question?

Comment: I see your content-type is normal, could you say me more clearly about the varibale "this.state.attachment" ? And in the console Chrome, could you view your request in Form Data and click view source for getting more infos of the data "attachment" ?

Comment: And normally what is the reponse of your request with which content-type (ex.: JSON) ?

Comment: You should provide more details (what implementation of HTTP is behind the API endpoint? What a jQuery request looks like?)

Comment: I updated my .Net Core version... and it was case sensitive whereas the older version wasn't.  So much wasted time :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older version of Core was not case sensitive when parsing incoming models, the newer version is.

Answer (score 2):

```
let options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
}
```

The semicolon `;` after `body` in the JSON declaration might cause errors on running. This could be a problem please do check for that. As you're attaching an attachment, check if it is converted properly into binary format. Hope it helps!! Happy Coding!!

Comment: Not sure how that ';' got in the question, input error on my part (that wasn't it).

Comment: As far a binary data, DevTools shows the Form Data exactly as I have above, with 'attachment: (binary)' so it appears so